# I wrote a ramp function but it's work wrong in some cases

Tags: matlab

I'm new to Matlab and I faced this problem:
I wrote a ramp function , it is work correctly if I plot ramp(t-1),ramp(t-2),ramp(t-3)....
but it doesn't work when I'm trying to plot ramp(t),ramp(t+1),ramp(t+2)....

here is my code:

```
    function [ y ] = ramp(x)
    y(x<0)=0;
    s = (abs(x(length(x)))+abs(x(1)))/length(x);% x(2)-x(1) or x(i)-x(i-1), EX:{1,1.2,1.4}s=0.2
    y(x>=0)= 0:s:x(length(x));

    end
```

Comment: consider using `numel` instead of `length`... also `linspace` as David suggests.

Comment: Just a quick Matlab tip: `x(length(x))` can be better written as `x(end)`, the `end` keyword when used in indexing gets you the last value or last row/column etc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't see reproduce any errors using your code, but here is a different way of doing the same thing.

```
function [ y ] = ramp(x)
    y=zeros(size(x));
    y(x>=0)=linspace(0,x(end),length(x(x>=0)))
end
```